# ASGI does not start in Django

Tags: django, websocket

I am following the tutorial by Dennis Ivy on YouTube: Django Channels & WebSockets Oversimplified

I want to make a simple website using websockets in Django. I am using Python 3.7.0

When I use the `python manage.py runserver` it outputs the following `Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/`
It should, however, output the following `Starting ASGI/Channels version 3.0.0 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

This is my settings.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'channels',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'chat',
]


ASGI_APPLICATION = 'myWebsite.asgi.application'
```

The asgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter 

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myWebsite.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http':get_asgi_application()
})
```

Comment: which version used of Django ?/

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're facing with ASGI not starting in Django often occurs in newer versions of Channels. To resolve this issue, you must install Daphne by executing the following command: `pip install daphne`. Once Daphne is installed, proceed to update Channels with Daphne support using the following command: `python -m pip install -U channels["daphne"]`.

Moreover, it is crucial to add 'daphne' at the top of the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in your Django's settings.py file. This ensures that Django recognizes and prioritizes Daphne when starting ASGI servers.

By following these steps, you should be able to resolve the issue and start ASGI successfully with Django.  Good luck!